# CSS how to change background color for specific dynamic element

Tags: css

Environment: WP plugin

Case: I am trying to change the background color of an item which shows on the website after a user checks a checkbox. The issue is that I have 3 of those items and they all have to get a unique background color. I managed to set one but it automatically targets all items.

Example of 1 element:

```
<div class="wapf-field-container wapf-field-p" style="width:100%;" for="60569cec7e1bc" data-wapf-d="[{"rules:[field":"60569cec7e1bc","condition":"==","value":"sdvmr","generated":false}]}]">
```

As you can see it has an ID (60569cec7e1bc) but I can't seem to figure out how to target it. I can only target the global class and give it a background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an attribute selector to target a specific element (as long as the value is different for the other elements) e.g.

```
[for="60569cec7e1bc"] {
   background: yellowgreen
}
```

Further information on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)